Building a collection of function outcomes using Kotlin and Arrow without using a mutable collection
I have a bit of a tricky problem. I have a Kotlin function that takes in three collections of data representing items that need to be 'deleted', 'updated', or 'added'. For each of those three datasets, I iterate through, calling the corresponding function to do the CRUD operation. While the CRUD functions have different implementations, they all return a arrow-kt 'Either', (https://apidocs.arrow-kt.io/arrow-core/arrow.core/-either/index.html) representing the outcome of the function.
Where things get tricky is that I want to keep a running list of all the 'left' (failed) results so that I can compile the errors into a report for the user. The simplest solution, and the one I am currently using, is to have a mutable list of errors that I can add to as each function gets called. It works, but it isn't a very 'functional' way of doing things. I feel like there must be a better way of doing this using functional programming that avoids mutable collections. Any ideas?
Update:
I found the 'mapOrAccumulate' library function. It is close but not quite what I need. It will return the errors OR the successes, but I need something that will give me both.
For reference, here is a simplified version of my existing code:
fun executeNightlyUpdate(toDelete:List,toAdd:List,toUpdate:List):List<Throwable>
{
    val j = dp.journalFactory()
    val errors = mutableListOf<Throwable>()

    toDelete.forEach { addressId ->
                deletePhoneLocation(dp, addressId).onLeft {
                    it.message?.let { it1 -> j.error(it1, it) }
                    errors.add(it)
                }
            }

    toUpdate.forEach { requestPair ->
                val( id, data) = requestPair
                findOrCreateEmergencyAddress(dp, incomingData.site_id, data.company_address).onLeft{
                    it.message?.let { it1 -> j.error(it1, it)}
                    errors.add(it)
                }
            }

    sendPhoneLocations( dp, BatchAddLocation.LocationsRequest(toAdd, incomingData.site_id) ).onLeft{
                    error->
                if (error is BatchLocationError) {
                    val errorMap: Map<String, Any>? = error.requestData.serializeToMap(dp.json.value())

                    val data = errorMap?.get(error.fieldName)
                    errors.add( "Location " + error.requestData.display_name + " failed to upload. Cause: " + error.message + " field: " + error.fieldName + "  value: " + data + "")
                }
            }

    return errors.toList()
}


I may not be able to provide a fully working solution, but it sounds the only thing you need is to create a list of eithers and then filter them for failed results. Something along lines:
val results = toDelete.map { addressId -> deletePhoneLocation(dp, addressId) }
    + toUpdate.map { requestPair -> ... }
    + listOf(sendPhoneLocations( dp, BatchAddLocation.LocationsRequest(toAdd, incomingData.site_id)))

val errors = results.filterIsInstance<Either.Left>()
    .map { it.value }

I skipped the special handling for toAdd as it doesn't seem right. You create a list of throwables and then you add a string to it (?). If you need this special handling, you have to add it for example by mapping the results.
